# Google drive, upload MemoryStream

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

This code is working well:

```
img.Save("111.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
using (MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("111.png")))
{
    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _drive.Files.Insert(item, fileStream, mimeType);
    request.Upload();
}
```

But when I try upload a `MemoryStream` received from `System.Drawing.Image`, I get an google Exception:
`'The given header was not found.'`

Code:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = myImgObj;
using (MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream()))
{        
    img.Save(fileStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _drive.Files.Insert(item, fileStream, mimeType);
    request.Upload();
}
```

Can anybody help me fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't like to say why you're getting that particular error, but after you've called `Save`, the stream's "cursor" is at the *end* of the data, so there's no data for `Insert` to read. You should rewind the stream:

```
img.Save(...);
fileStream.Position = 0;
```

I'd also suggest that `fileStream` is a somewhat misleading name for a `MemoryStream` variable...